# Get Menu Group as View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm using the [MaterialShowcaseView](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) to give users an overview of my app. set a target for the showcase, it must be a `View`. Below is an example of a sequence:

```
String SHOWCASE_ID = getString(R.string.showcase_id);

ShowcaseConfig config = new ShowcaseConfig();
config.setDelay(500); // half second between each showcase view

MaterialShowcaseSequence sequence = new MaterialShowcaseSequence(this, SHOWCASE_ID);

sequence.setConfig(config);

...

sequence.addSequenceItem(
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(findViewById(R.id.navigation_header))
                .setDismissText(getString("GOT IT"))
                .setTitleText(getString(R.string.onboarding_navigation_header_title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.onboarding_navigation_header_content))
                .withRectangleShape(false)
                .build());
 ...

sequence.start();
```

In this example, I'm targeting the navigation header of the following `NavigationView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/main_navigation"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
```

How would I get the menu in the snippet above as a `View` so I can pass that into`setTarget()` for my showcase sequence?

I have tried using just the `NavigationView`, but that targets both the header layout and the menu. I have also tried getting a group of the menu by ID (`findViewById(R.id.menu_group_id)`), but I don't believe the menu group is technically a `View`. I can get the menu via `NavigationView.getMenu()`, but that returns a `Menu` object. Any ideas?

Edit: The entire menu needs to be targeted. On a side note,this `NavigationView` exists in a `DrawerLayout`, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the view reference of menu group in NavigationView. You could [remove](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView#removeheaderview) or hide the header view at runtime when targets NavigationView, and [add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView#addheaderview) or show the header view again when targets other.

you could use [getheaderview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView#getheaderview) to get the header and call:

```
your_header.setVisibility(View.GONE)    //hide
your_header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) //show
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the menu items by using them as [action views](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views). Set the `actionViewClass` in your `menu.xml` like so:

```
<item
    ...
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"
/>
```

And then in your activity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    ...

    sequence.addSequenceItem(
            new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                    .setTarget(findViewById(R.id.navigation_header))
                    .setDismissText(getString("GOT IT"))
                    .setTitleText(getString(R.string.onboarding_navigation_header_title))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.onboarding_navigation_header_content))
                    .withRectangleShape(false)
                    .build());
     ...

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Would that not target the menu item instead of the menu itself? Also, your `setTarget` in your snippet does not reflect the point you're trying to make.